# Styling the cursor outside the document body

Tags: css

I have a pupil with poor vision and am using an alternative cursor. I use a css class to change the cursor in the body (for this pupil only) but it changes back to normal in the areas of the viewport that are not in the body. Is there anyway of setting the cursor for the whole viewport in a way that I can toggle it?

The pages in question have an area at the top of the viewport that asks a question (about maths) and areas to the left and right with arrows to go to the next and previous questions and a small area at the bottom with a div containing the question number. The transparent question number div is fixed in position at the bottom of the page and may cover the question text if the question is sufficiently large. It is a common format shared by hundreds of similar programs.
In all of these areas the cursor is transformed into a large cursor but not any other areas as they are not in the document body. When the question is very large and fills the viewport this is not an issue. It is only a problem when the question is smaller so there is a gap between the question text and the question number div. I have tried setting the height and min-height of the body to 100% but it has no effect.
Is there any way I can change the cursor to the large one in these areas too? It must be possible to switch back to the auto cursor for the other pupils.

```
js:
var bodyEl = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
if (myPupil == 3){
    bodyEl.classList.add("bigCursor");
}
else {
    bodyEl.classList.remove("bigCursor");
}
css:
.bigCursor {
    cursor: url('../../../cursor/Giant Rainbow.cur'), auto;
}
.bigCursor :hover {
    cursor: url('../../../cursor/Giant Rainbow.cur'), auto;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, thanks for reading, I have just worked out how to do it:

instead of

```
body { height: 100%; }
```

I used

```
body { height: 100vh; }
```

and this caused the body to fill the viewport so the cursor was transformed as required.